# Cannot create a React app with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am facing a problem with creating a new React app using **CRA** when I run the following command `npx create-react-app my-app`.

- I tried to clear npm cache with this command `npm cache clean --force`
- I also tried this command `npm -g uninstall create-react-app`

My node version is `v14.15.3` and the npm version is `7.10.0` 
The error which I get is :

```sh
Need to install the following packages:
  create-react-app
Ok to proceed? (y)
```

Comment: this is not an error. what did you get after proceeding?

Comment: create-react-app is not recognized as an internal or external command...

Comment: it seems like a path variable issue. which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 10

Comment: could you check `echo %Path%`

Comment: ```C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;;C:\Users\pc cam\AppData\Roaming\npm;...```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Options 1 
   Switch to yarn instead of npm

   ```
   npm i -g yarn
   yarn create react-app
   ```
2. Options 2 
   Uninstal Node completely and re-instal it again
3. Option 3  
   Use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) (Node Version Manager)

Answer (score 44):

Need to clear the cache on the npx:

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

and then re-run

```
npx create-react-app <app-name>
```

and then accept (y)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Clearing npx cache and re-running cra command worked.

Comment: Make sure you're using a current version of Node for this... Our app happens to be using 10.15.3 (barf) so the cache clean wouldn't work and the whole thing wouldn't work. Finally remembered to switch to Node 16+ with nvm, and this solution worked.

Answer (score 16):

Just had the same problem. This worked for me:

- npm -g uninstall create-react-app
- npm cache clean --force
- npm install -g create-react-app
- npx create-react-app my-app

Answer (score 2):

Just clear the cache by running, `npx clear-npx-cache` and then try to create your react app `npx creact-react-app my-app`.

Answer (score 1):

When it said
`Ok to proceed? (y)` 
I went through that twice and it told me the version I was using was no longer supported so,
`npm update`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30624237)

Answer (score 1):

Hi Oussama Bouchikhi,

You can try the following `npm` commands to solve the issue:

Run this first,

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

then

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Here's the snapshot of the same,
[create-react-app-issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFZxj.png)

Let us know if it works!
Happy Hacking!

Answer (score 0):

When it gives you this error, it asks your permission to install `create-react-app`

```
...
Ok to proceed? (y)
```

**Type `y` in your terminal and press `enter`**

You might find this helpful as well:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

> If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm
> install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package
> using npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove
> create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.

Comment: I get this "create-react-app is not recognized as an internal or external command..."

Answer (score 0):

could you try to add this path to your system variable?
`C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\npm`

and try again with `npx create-react-app <app-name>`

Comment: I think it's already in the environment variables ```C:\Users\pc cam\AppData\Roaming\npm```

Comment: in your path there is a space in your username. afaik it shouldn't be like this. space broke the path link I think

Comment: I changed the user name and I still get the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your npx cache first.

Delete the folder `_npx` inside the path returned by `npm config get cache`

```sh
# In Linux/MacOS terminal
rm -rf `npm config get cache`/_npx
```

This can also be done with [@snewn's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70389842/1465277), I posted this in case you want to skip that dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Need to clear the cache on the npx:

npx clear-npx-cache
and then re-run

npx create-react-app 
and then accept (y)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the same as the top-voted answer, but without formatted code blocks.